# How to create an associative hash with multiple arrays?

Tags: bash

I have dozens of files, half TSV and half CSV. I'm copying from specfic columns in each of them and pasting that into a new TSV file. I have the code for that below:

```
paste <(cut -d , -f 3 -s file.csv) <(cut -f 2 -s file.tsv) > merged.tsv
```

The TSV and CSV files share ID's in the filenames. For example mary.tsv/mary.csv and joseph.tsv/joseph.csv.

How can I substitute in mary.tsv and mary.csv into the `cut` commands by associating them their filenames together?

So far I have:

```
tsvarray=(`find . -iname "*.tsv"`)
csvarray=(`find . -iname "*.csv"`)
```

I could then do something like the code below inside a for loop?

```
paste <(cut -d , -f 3 -s $csvarray[@] <(cut -f 2 -s $tsvarray[@]) > merged.tsv
```

Comment: Why would you need a `for` loop when you use `[@]` as the subscript to get the entire array?

Comment: You should sort the arrays so they're in the same order.

Comment: Post a couple of sample files with the expected output.

Comment: `$foo[@]` is not `"${foo[@]}"` -- the curly braces (and quotes) are mandatory.

Comment: Then again, ```tsvarray=(`find . -iname "*.tsv"`)``` also is not `readarray -d '' tsvarray < <(find . -iname '*.tsv' -print0)` (the former can't deal with filenames with spaces, or filenames that word-split into pieces that can be evaluated as glob expressions, to give you some examples)

Comment: Suppose I wanted to name the output using the ID in my filename, is there a quick way of doing that using the arrays already created? Would creating a third array just for the ID's be the best way of doing this?

Comment: BTW, once you have `tsvarray`, you could run `csvarray=( "${tsvarray[@]/%.tsv/.csv}" )` if you just want to duplicate the prior array but change each `.tsv` to a `.csv` -- see the "anchoring" section in https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#search_and_replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `for` loop. But you do need to make sure that the two arrays have filenames in the same order, so you should sort them.

You can use `readarray` and options in `find` and `sort` so that you don't have problems when filenames have spaces:

```
readarray -d '' tsvarray < <(find . -iname '*.tsv' -print0 | sort -z)
readarray -d '' csvarray < <(find . -iname '*.csv' -print0 | sort -z)
```

Then you need to use the correct syntax for referring to a subscripted array. You need `{}` around it. Then you should quote it, again to prevent problems when filenames contain whitespace.

```
paste <(cut -d , -f 3 -s "${csvarray[@]}") <(cut -f 2 -s "${tsvarray[@]}") > merged.tsv
```

This also assumes every `.csv` has a matching `.tsv` and vice versa. Otherwise the arrays will not correspond.

If you want separate merged files for each csv/tsv pair, you *will* need a loop:

```
for ((i = 0; i < ${#tsvarray[@]}; i++)); do
    paste <(cut -d , -f 3 -s "${csvarray[$i]}") <(cut -f 2 -s "${tsvarray[$i]}") > "${csvarray[$i]/.csv/.merged.csv}"
done
```

Comment: I'd argue that it would be much more appropriate to demonstrate `readarray -d '' tsvarray < <(find . -iname '*.tsv' -print0 | sort -z) ` so as not to be showcasing code with known/obvious bugs (relevant: [BashPitfalls #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29)).

Comment: thankyou for a great answer. Suppose I wanted to name the output using the ID in my filename, is there a quick way of doing that using the arrays already created?

Comment: If you want a separate merged file for each input file, you'll need a loop, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Yes, thankyou for updating it with the loop, I was just about to put it into one!. When using your readarray command I get a readarray usage option. I think its the -d it doesn't like, any ideas?

Comment: What version of `bash` are you using?

Comment: The `-d` option was added in bash 4.4.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Is there a solution for pre-4.4 bash?

Comment: `tsvarray=( ); while IFS= read -r -d '' piece; do tsvarray+=( "$piece" ); done < <(find ...)`